# Question about linear independence of linear equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Why can you say that these 2 functions are Linearly Independent using derivatives? By taking the derivative don't you find only the $c_1$ of the derivative?
$c_1e^{λ_1x}+c_2e^{λ_2x}=0$ $\implies$ $ c_1 + c_1e^{(λ_2−λ_1)x} ≡ 0$

Now by taking the derivative you find: $(λ_2−λ_1)c_2e^{(λ_2−λ_1)x}$ $\implies$ $c_2=0$ And $c_1=0$

Comment: There are two unknowns $c_1, c_2$ so you need a second equation...

Comment: Oh, so I can use the derivative as my second equation. Thank you